# Blazor webassembly with authorization fails with failed to fetch on blazor.boot.json

Tags: blazor-webassembly, asp.net-authorization

I added authorization to an asp.net hosted web assembly app. When starting the app it correctly starts to redirects to the login page but then only shows a white screen. In the javascript console I see error "failed to fetch" for blazor.boot.json. Firefox reports this as NS_BINDING_ABRORTED. Strangely running this in chrome reports the same javascript error but fiddler reports a 304. Worst is that this was working in the past and stopped working. I moved back many commits in the git repository of my project and none works, so it was not a recent change. I installed the code on a new machine and get same error there.

See attached screenshots:

[image: Firefox screenshot]

[image: Fiddler screenshot]

Comment: Who clicked on "close" , what purpose does that have without ant comment ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to my answer:

1.) The failed to fetch error still exists and I think it is a blazor bug as the authorization redirects so I think started request just get cancelled and this is not caught.

2.) The reason why I had a white screen was similar. CSS hides everything until my code sets it and it was a race condition if this was not finished before the redirect triggers, it never set the display value.

So posting this here if people get the "failed to fetch" error, that it seems to do no harm.